# Jade rendering issue with express, passportjs, and angularjs/ngRoute routing with mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, pug, passport.js

any help on this would be greatly appreciated!  I've been struggling with this for the past day and half now.

The issue I'm currently dealing with is getting my authenticated user route to load in my ng-view, where everything else does.

The following images depict what my issue looks like.

[1. login screen within ng-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZincQ.png)

[2. successful login routes to new page instead of ng-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DovcB.png)

**Here is my code**

**login.jade**

```
block content
   form(method="POST" action="/")
      div
         label(for="username").
            Username:
         input(type="text" name="username" id="username")
      div
         label(for="password").
            Password:
         input(type="password" name="password" id="password")
      div
         input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

**Jade HTML**

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myApp")
  head
    title= title

    script(src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js")
    script(src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js")
    script(src="/vendor/angular-material/angular-material.min.js")
    script(src="/vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js")
    script(src="/vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/client.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/AboutController.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/ArchivesController.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/RegisterController.js")

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/vendor/angular-material/angular-material.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

    base(href="/")

  body.site
    .container
        nav
            img.logo(src="/images/logo.png")
            ul.nav
                li
                  a(href="/")
                    i.fa.fa-home.fa-3
                li
                  a(href="/archives")
                    i.fa.fa-archive.fa-3
                li
                  a(href="/about")
                    i.fa.fa-info.fa-3
                li
                  a(href="/register")
                    i.fa.fa-folder-open.fa-3

        block content
        div(ng-view)

    block footer
    footer
        div.navigation
          h4 Navigation
        div.links
          h4 Links
        div.github
          h4 Github Feed
        div.twitter
          h4 Twitter Feed
```

**Client Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/about',{
            templateUrl: '/about',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        })
        .when('/archives',{
            templateUrl: '/archives',
            controller: 'ArchivesController'
        })
        .when('/register',{
            templateUrl: '/register',
            controller: 'RegisterController'
        })
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: '/login'
        })
        .when('/profile',{
            templateUrl: '/profile',
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**Routes**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

/* GET home page. */

//router.get('/:name', function (req, res)
//{ var name = req.params.name;
//    res.render(name);
//});

router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile',{
        user : req.user
    });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Ryan Merchlewitz Home Page' });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Ryan Merchlewitz Home Page' });
});

router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    })
);


// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Here is a link to my project repo: https://github.com/rmerk/personal_project